# How can I transform this table into Latex?

Tags: tables, matrices, arrays

I am struggling a lot to adapt this figure from Sheppard & Barnes (1990) into LaTeX:

[image]

What do you suggest? :)

Comment: Welcome. // I suggest to scan this site: there are many similar requests. And I suggest to post your attempts (EDIT), as the rules you read say.

Comment: Maybe the `nicematrix` package could be used for this ... May I ask how the three *t* in the header above the table should be positioned exactly?

Comment: Show hat you have tried. This is not a "do it for me site". Provide an MWE that we can compile that shows what you have done and what your problem is. Why should we guess as to what you might, or might not have doe. If you need help then please help any any prospetive assistants.Your question is equivalent tro "I baged a cake but it was inedible.

Answer (score 7):

This site works best if you show what you tried so far, because it is far easier to help you solve the problems you got stuck with. I take it that you are quite lost at how to start with this in general, so I’ll still provide the following answer, also because it serves as nice exercise for me, too.

Having said that, a solution using the `nicematrix` package could be:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix, tikz}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash$}p{#1}<{$}}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
$\begin{NiceArray}{ 
    c c P{4em} P{2em} P{4em} P{2em} P{6em} P{4em} P{2em}
}
 & & \Block{1-2}{\textrm{Region 1}} & 
        & \Block{1-2}{\textrm{Region 2}} & & \cdots 
        & \Block{1-2}{\textrm{Region J}} & \\
 & & & t & & t & & & t \\
\Block{5-1}{\textrm{Region 1}}
 & 1      & \Block{4-1}{a^{mn}_{11}} & \Block{4-1}{a^{mt}_{11}}
        & \Block{4-1}{a^{mn}_{12}} & \Block{4-1}{a^{mt}_{12}} &
        & \Block{4-1}{a^{mn}_{1J}} & \Block{4-1}{a^{mt}_{1J}} \\
 & 2      & & & & & & & \\
 & \vdots & & & & & & & \\
 & N      & & & & & & & \\
 & t      & a^{tn}_{11} & & a^{tn}_{12} & & & a^{tn}_{1J} & \\ 
%
\Block{5-1}{\textrm{Region 2}}
 & 1      & \Block{4-1}{a^{mn}_{21}} & \Block{4-1}{a^{mt}_{21}}
        & \Block{4-1}{a^{mn}_{22}} & \Block{4-1}{a^{mt}_{22}} &
        & \Block{4-1}{a^{mn}_{2J}} & \Block{4-1}{a^{mt}_{2J}} \\
 & 2      & & & & & & & \\
 & \vdots & & & & & & & \\
 & N      & & & & & & & \\
 & t      & a^{tn}_{21} & & a^{tn}_{22} & & & a^{tn}_{2J} & \\ 
%
\raisebox{-1.5em}{\vdots}    
 & & & & & & & \\[3em]
%
\Block{5-1}{\textrm{Region J}}
 & 1      & \Block{4-1}{a^{mn}_{J1}} & \Block{4-1}{a^{mt}_{J1}}
        & \Block{4-1}{a^{mn}_{J2}} & \Block{4-1}{a^{mt}_{J2}} &
        & \Block{4-1}{a^{mn}_{JJ}} & \Block{4-1}{a^{mt}_{JJ}} \\
 & 2      & & & & & & & \\
 & \vdots & & & & & & & \\
 & N      & & & & & & & \\
 & t      & a^{tn}_{J1} & & a^{tn}_{J2} & & & a^{tn}_{JJ} & \\ 
\CodeAfter
    \SubMatrix({2-3}{18-9})
    \tikz {
        \draw[dashed] (7-|3) -- (7-|10) (12-|3) -- (12-|10) (18-|3) -- (18-|10);
        \draw         (8-|2) -- (8-|10) (13-|2) -- (13-|10) (14-|2) -- (14-|10);
        \draw[dashed] (3-|4) -- (19-|4) (3-|6) -- (19-|6) (3-|9) -- (19-|9);
        \draw         (3-|5) -- (19-|5) (3-|7) -- (19-|7) (3-|8) -- (19-|8);
    }
\end{NiceArray}$
\end{document}
```

[image]